# make webview content always fit width of the screen

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a webpage that has data in a table that I want to make viewable in my Android App through a webview. My problem is that the table varies in width, sometimes its 400px sometimes its 1000px. I am trying to make it so that regardless of the width, the table fills the webview so that the user doesnt have to zoom in or out, or scroll horizontally. I have it working on my Galaxy s2, but on other devices like the Nexus 5x, the page starts zoomed way out and the user has to zoom in to even read anything. Zoomed out, the content is only filling 50% of the screen and I don't know where all that extra space is coming from.

Here is what I have setup to make it work on the Galaxy s2:

html:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.1" />`

this made it so that it started zoomed all the way out, when the content was only 400px it wouldn't look zoomed way out.

Android Webview:

```
WebSettings settings = w.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

useWideViewPort was the only way I could get it to allow the user to zoom out enough to not have to scroll horizontally.

Here is what it looks like on my Galaxy s2, this is how the page loads and the user cannot zoom out anymore, then when the page has the table (not in the screenshot) the same page is zoomed out further to fit the table so that it takes up 100% of the screen width. exactly how I want it:

[image: galaxys2 screenshot]

The same page on the Nexus 5x looks like this, way too zoomed out, and when the table is there it doesn't even take up half of the width of the screen:

[image: nexus5x screenshot]

Any help is appreciated, Iv'e tried messing with the config / meta tags a lot just to get it to work on the galaxy.

Setting the table to 100% just makes it stretch to fill the nexus screen, which makes the text too small and the columns too far apart.

**Edit:** just to clarify, I took the horizontal screenshots because I know that if the content isn't wide enough to fit the device screen at normal zoom then it will add whitespace, and that's fine. My problem is both screenshots are zoomed out as far as they can be, I'd like to know why the second is even able to zoom out that far,and how to prevent it.

**Edit2:** As a temporary fix, I have set the viewport width to one of two values depending on if the screen is going to be wide or narrow. I set everything to 100% width, but the viewport width is either set to 400 or 1000 depending on whether or not the content of the table is larger:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=<?php echo ($wideContent?"1000":"400"); ?>, initial-scale=.1" />`

This is working for now, but in the future I am going to need more widths and it would be much better if it just automatically adjusted.

Comment: You can add css to the webview. Use css properties to fit its content to the screen

Comment: `initial-scale=1` not `.1`. Is that your problem?

Comment: no, I originally had 1 but then i would have to zoom out to fit the content on the screen. setting it to .1 made it zoom out as far as it could, which on my s2 fits everything, the nexus has all this white space causing it to zoom out even further.